# How to RECOMPLE the DLL of Uploaded ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net

Good day everyone, i just need a little help from you regarding the recompilation of ASP Website DLL.

I'm an amateur web developer and I know some of you also experience this, as we finished uploading our ASP website over the internet, sometimes, we forgot some important features that require server-side codes, and for me, my way of editing an ASP .cs file or .config file is by using FileZilla, which I just need to choose the specific file I want to edit and View/Edit it. Now the problem is, everytime I make some changes on such files, when i re-upload it, the codes that I added can no longer be read. So I presume, it's a DLL problem, so just to solve it, I downloaded the whole website again and recompiled it, and i erased again the one that's on the server and uploaded the updated one. It always takes more than an hour to complete the upload/download, which is really exhausting and time consuming, just to edit one file among thousands of files. So can anyone suggest an easier way to do it? Any reply regarding this concern will be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

You should consider setting up local (development) and production environments. Then you'd test your changes locally and then deploy your ASP.NET files to your production environment. Depending on version of VS.NET that you use, you may use different approaches for deployment. Refer to the following links for more information:

[VS.NET 2005 ASP.NET Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178610%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[VS.NET 2010 Web Deployment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx)

Comment: Thanks man, I'm using VS 2010 for web app development. I'll take a look at those links.